# jQuery stopwatch counting down with reset

Tags: jquery, countdown, stopwatch, reset-button

I'm looking for a jQuery stopwatch for my project. Just did a fast search on google if i could use anything that's already made. But didn't find anything fiting my project, cause I need it to be set to X minutes, countdown to zero. There also need to be a reset button so it restarts at X minutes when reseted. 
Found this nice one:
http://www.kellishaver.com/projects/stopwatch/

Should I modify it to meet my needs or should I do something from scratch?
Any ideas are welcome thnx. :)

Edit:

Got it to work as I wanted, read here if you wonder how I did...
[jQuery make kellishaver stopwatch plugin countdown instead of up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772895/jquery-make-kellishaver-stopwatch-plugin-countdown-instead-of-up/7772930#7772930)

Comment: There's a great comment in the plugin you've linked; `// parseInt() doesn't work here...` because he's trying to parse `00`,`01`,`02` etc. If only the author knew about the radix param.

Comment: doing it from scratch would waste your time, instead take something like jquery timer plugin and alter it according to your requirements

Comment: So I decided to modify the plugin i posted... But run into problems, found where the 'second++;' was added but if i changed it to 'second--;' i got this result=00:03:0-1. Didn't really understand what you were talking about Jamiec, whats radix param?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through the stopwatch jQuery plugin, and it seems easy enough to just modify it to your needs rather than coding your own, unless you want to gain the experience.

Personally, I would code my own to gain experience and gives me more control over it.