# jQuery make kellishaver stopwatch plugin countdown instead of up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a stopwatch/timer to countdown. I'm trying to use [Kellis Havers stopwatch jQuery plugin](http://www.kellishaver.com/projects/stopwatch/) and change it to countdown.

But can't figure out how to make it substract instead of add seconds, tried changing the 'second++;' to 'second--;' but got this result= 00:03:0-1. It says in the comments that parseInt() is not working, so i figure it something with the seconds is written in 01 02 03 04 etc.

But I am not yet good enough to understand how to get it to countdown.

```
function do_time() {
            // parseInt() doesn't work here...
            hour = parseFloat(h.text());
            minute = parseFloat(m.text());
            second = parseFloat(s.text());

            second++;

            if(second > 59) {
                second = 0;
                minute = minute + 1;
            }
            if(minute > 59) {
                minute = 0;
                hour = hour + 1;
            }

            h.html("0".substring(hour >= 10) + hour);
            m.html("0".substring(minute >= 10) + minute);
            s.html("0".substring(second >= 10) + second);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` will work fine if you [include 10 as a second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Change to:

```
        hour = parseInt(h.text(),10);
        minute = parseInt(m.text(),10);
        second = parseInt(s.text(),10);

        second--;

        if(second < 0) {
            second = 59;
            minute = minute - 1;
        }

        if(minute < 0) {
            minute = 59;
            hour = hour - 1;
        }

        h.html("0".substring(hour >= 10) + hour);
        m.html("0".substring(minute >= 10) + minute);
        s.html("0".substring(second >= 10) + second);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MgAKA/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/MgAKA/2/ -- slightly improved version that actually stops when the clock reaches zero -- may be harder to combine with the plugin, though.

Comment: thank you! I used your first version, already made it stop at 00:00 :) Just did a if second == 0 then stop... Don't know what's better. Thank you for fast reply :)